# UnknownHostException is thrown in android app if hostname is used instead of IP address

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have the following code which I use to send a request to the server.

```
String inputXML = createInputXML(searchText);
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
String url = "http://mysite.com/action";//Works fine if I use IP address directly,for eg:http://1.2.3.4/action
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
HttpResponse response=null;
StringEntity se = null;
try {
    se = new StringEntity(inputXML, HTTP.UTF_8);
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
se.setContentType("text/xml");  
httppost.setHeader("Content-Type","application/xml;charset=UTF-8");
httppost.setEntity(se);  
try {
    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I run the program on emulator I am getting a UnKnownHostException on the line

`response = httpclient.execute(httppost);`

If I use the ip address directly instead of host name,the request is sent correctly.
Please note the following points:

1. I am using Android 2.3.3
2. I have added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>` in the manifest xml
3. Proxy settings are updated in the emulator's APN.
4. Using the browser in the emulator I can access a website with their host names.

Any idea why this is causing an issue?

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem? this could really help me. I have EXACT the same probloems (APN setttings up to date, android2.3.3, permission set, Browser is working)

Comment: I found the answer now, it's possible to get the APN Proxy settings from the device and use them. Unfortunately my project is on another Computer in my office, but I'll post it tomorrow morning. Remind me if i forget.

Comment: Sure..Please post it as an answer and I will mark it as correct.Anyway I am not doing this android project now.But it can be useful to others facing the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure, you followed  all steps 1-4 user700284 described in his Question.

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();


//Get the default settings from APN (could be also hard coded stuff)
  String proxyHost = android.net.Proxy.getDefaultHost();
  int proxyPort = android.net.Proxy.getDefaultPort();
//Set Proxy params of client, if they are not the standard
    if (proxyHost != null && proxyPort > 0) {
        HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort);
        client.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);
    }
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

The url has nothing to do with the line

```
se = new StringEntity(inputXML, HTTP.UTF_8);
```

are you sure it is this line?

Comment: have you tried to put a www. infront of the url and have you tried to open the site in the browser?

Comment: yes.I also tried adding www.Infact the url I used in the example is not the actual url.It is just for illustration purpose only.In the browser in emulator i can open the site.